# Creating new SpannableStringBuilder returns null

Tags: java, android, spannablestringbuilder

Here is my unit test. Somehow when I create instantiate SpannableStringBuilder instance with a non-null string argument, it appears to be null. What's wrong with this code?

```
public class CardNumberTextWatcherTest {

private CardNumberTextWatcher watcher;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    watcher = new CardNumberTextWatcher();
}


@Test
public void afterTextChanged_cardNumberDividedWithSpaces() {
    assertTransformText("1111222233334444", "1111 2222 3333 4444");
}

private void assertTransformText(final String testStr,
                                 final String expectedStr) {
    final CardNumberTextWatcher watcher = new CardNumberTextWatcher();
    final Editable actualStr = new SpannableStringBuilder(testStr);
    // When I debug I see that actualStr value is null. Therefore test 
    //doesn't pass. What's the problem?
    watcher.transformText(actualStr);
    assertEquals(expectedStr, actualStr.toString());
}


}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace or test output?

Comment: Please share your exception stack trace so we can help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was in the testing directory. As soon as `SpannableStringBuilder` is a part of Android SDK, it couldn't be resolved in regular JUnit test directory. When I **moved my class to androidTest directory**, everything started to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the same issue. Actually don't know, why this question was so minused.

Answer (score 4):

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
```

Using Robolectric resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `actualStr.toString()` which is what the assertion is comparing with, not `actualStr` itself so look for routes through `SpannableStringBuilder` to see what could result in `null` from `toString()`. Probably `testStr` is `null`.